# How to reset Meteor AutoForm when page changed?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have page with text fields, this fields are required.
I click 'submit' with empty fields => fields with red border (because it is required). Then I change page and return back => borders are still shown. How to reset meteor AutoForm when page changed? Thanks.

Comment: Please paste your code as well..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to clear existing validation errors, you need to call `AutoForm.resetForm("form-id");`. You could put this call inside the `Template.myTemplate.onDestroyed` function, which will be triggered when the template is removed from the DOM and destroyed, i.e. on route change.

For instance:

```
Template.myTemplate.onDestroyed(function () {
  AutoForm.resetForm("form-id");
});
```

Or you could use [routing hooks](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#hooks) (assuming you use [Iron Router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router)):

```
var myResetFormFunction = function () {
    AutoForm.resetForm("form-id");
};

Router.onStop(myResetFormFunction, {
    only: ['routeOne']
});
```